# Explicit formula for Stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, stirling-numbers

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), there is an explicit formula for Stirling numbers of the first kind:

$$\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_{k-1}<n} \frac{(n-1)!}{i_1i_2\cdots i_{k-1}} =s(n,k)$$

What is the proof of this? I understand if it is too long to post here, so a reference direction would be fine.

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: Hint: The Stirling numbers are the change-of-basis coefficients when converting from the rising factorial basis for polynomials to the usual basis: $$x(x+1)\cdots (x+n-1)=\sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k)x^k$$ This shows $s(n,k)$ are the coefficients of a monic polynomial with roots $0,-1,\dots,-(n-1)$. Use Vieta's formula to express $s(n,k)$ as an elementary symmetric function of these roots. After realizing that $(n-1)!/(i_1\cdots i_{k-1})$ is the product of all numbers in $\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ except for $\{i_1,\dots,i_{k-1}\}$, your formula falls out.

Comment: @jjagmath maybe I'm out of line here, but this question seems fine to me. I don't think they're "just trying to get others to solve it for [them]," hence the purpose of the reference-request tag.